# Overcast app: Do Smart Playlists have a limit on the number of episodes they can contain?

Tags: iphone, podcasts, playlist

I use Overcast on my iPhone and have several Smart Playlists set up.  I was using one of them to play back the entire back catalogs of 4 podcasts that I wanted to catch up on.  This is roughly 500 episodes altogether.  I had no trouble creating the playlist but when I look at the list of included episodes it leaves out several hundred of the oldest episodes and seems to start the list at an arbitrary point in time and go from there to the present.

If I look at each of the podcasts individually I've marked all of the episodes in each one unplayed and can see all episodes in each one.  If I play from the individual podcast then it starts with the oldest episode and automatically moves to the next newer one when finished.  It's only in the Smart Playlist that I can't see the oldest episodes.

If I create a new Smart Playlist and only include one of the podcasts then I see all of the episodes for that podcast.  When I add another one it to the playlist I suddenly can't see the oldest episodes from either one any more.

Is there a limit on the number of episodes that can be in a playlist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a Twitter account, I'd suggest you tweet a link to this question over to the Overcast developer (Marco Arment): https://twitter.com/marcoarment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this question was asked, all playlists and shows in Overcast had a limit of 500 episodes. As of Overcast 2022.2, there is no limit.

Source: https://twitter.com/OvercastFM/status/1507412297106472969